# Entity Framework error while saving changes

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework. At the moment I'm having a problem - when I try to insert a new `User` object into the database (using method `RegisterNewUser`), I keep getting an error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Users__3214EC07705D23AE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (0).

There are some similar questions here, but none of these answers have helped me.

```
public void RegisterNewUser(String uName, String uPass, String fName, String lName, String email)
{
        User user = new User();
        user.Username = uName;
        user.Password = uPass;
        user.FirstName = fName;
        user.LastName = lName;
        user.Email = email;

        Time time = new Time();
        time.Time1 = DateTime.Now;

        user.Times.Add(time);

        ur.AddUser(user);
}
```

`Time` and `User` objects:

```
public partial class Time
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Time1 { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Times = new HashSet<Time>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Time> Times { get; set; }
}
```

Repository file

```
public class UsersRepository
{
    UsersDBContext userDBContext = new UsersDBContext();

    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return userDBContext.Users.Include("Times").ToList();
    }

    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        userDBContext.Users.Add(user);
        userDBContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And context

```
public partial class UsersDBContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersDBContext() : base("name=UsersDBContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Time> Times { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea how to solve this so any suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: `User.Id` should also be an identity column in the database.

Comment: Ah yes mark `public int Id { get; set; }` with `[Key]`

Comment: Well I do succeed to insert first user, but then when I try to insert another, it seems that the Id counting resets and it's trying to save new user with an id of 0

Comment: That's because User.Id isn't incremented by the database, change it into an identity column.

Comment: Did you check the column definition *in the database*? I'm 100% sure it's not an identity column. There's nothing in EF that resets identities.

Comment: Yeah, it was indeed not an identity column. However, Ive changed it to this:  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]        INT  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]  TEXT NOT NULL,
    [Password]  TEXT NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] TEXT NOT NULL,
    [LastName]  TEXT NOT NULL,
    [Email]     TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Comment: Now it says that SET IDENTITY_INSERT should be set to on in order to insert new element. How can I change it?

Comment: You *also* need the `DatabaseGeneratedOption`. They work as a tandem.

Comment: I did use 'DatabaseGeneratedOption', check my code

Comment: I just updated my edmx file and it worked!!! Thank you for your help very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a value of Id field

or

define the Id field as autoincrement

Comment: How could I define as autoincrement? I've tried [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]